# Создание SOAP запроса

Tags: php, soap

Опыта в разработке веб сервисов не много поэтому решил обратиться за советом. Есть такой запрос

```
$xmlRequest =   '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
$xmlRequest .=      '<soapenv:Header/>';
$xmlRequest .=      '<soapenv:Body>';
$xmlRequest .=          '<request_type>' . $type .'</request_type>';
$xmlRequest .=          '<msisdn>' . $msisdn . '</msisdn>';
$xmlRequest .=          '<newmsisdn>' . $msisdn . '</newmsisdn>';
$xmlRequest .=      '</soapenv:Body>';
$xmlRequest .=   '</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

При парсинге такого стринга через DomDocument, получаю пустоту. Обязательно ли узлы которые заключены в `Body` заключать в какой то главый узел и указывать ему namespace?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlRequest);

print_r($dom);

DOMDocument Object
(
)
```

Comment: Покажите код которым парсите.

Comment: Добавил в вопросе

Comment: И что интересно, запустил на другом сервере скрипт, вернул объект с данными,с чем может быть связана данная проблема?

Comment: бывает полезно у php спрашивать об ошибках. Смотреть логи тоже бывает полезно

Comment: Ошибок нет, погуглил и понял что это из за версий php на сервере стоит 5.3 на 5.6 уже дает нужный результат. Спасибо